# Python-Poetry Errors Publishing to Artifactory

Tags: artifactory, python-poetry

I'm having a dickens of a time publishing to our Artifactory instance using poetry (1.1.12). I've tried a couple different URL's to publish to, and I either get a 405 (Method not Allowed), or a 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

```
https://my.domain/artifactory/my-cool-reg/  --> 405
https://my-cool-reg.my.domain/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi/simple/  -> 415
```

Is there some magic that I'm missing to get publishing going? I have tried passing my credentials both with `-u` and `-p` on the CLI, as well as with the credential config for the `repository` via `-r my_repo`. Below is an example error message (from the pypi url test)

```
  UploadError

  HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type

  at ~/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/poetry/publishing/uploader.py:216 in _upload
      212│                     self._register(session, url)
      213│                 except HTTPError as e:
      214│                     raise UploadError(e)
      215│ 
    → 216│             raise UploadError(e)
      217│ 
      218│     def _do_upload(
      219│         self, session, url, dry_run=False
      220│     ):  # type: (requests.Session, str, Optional[bool]) -> None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By gum, I've figured it out

`$ poetry config repositories.poetry-repo-name https://artifactory.domain.lan/artifactory/api/pypi/your-cool-repository`

Answer (score 3):

geudrik - For the PyPI deployment, local configuration (.pypirc) should be defined with the API endpoint as `http://pythonpublishtest.com/artifactory/api/pypi/test-pypi-local`

**/api/pypi** is the required endpoint and the **test-pypi-local** I have mentioned in the URL here is the local repository. The reason for the HTTP 405 and HTTP 415 errors could be due to missing/incorrect API endpoint or the missing deployment repository.

I see that you are attempting to publish with the following URL (`https://my-cool-reg.my.domain/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi/simple/`). Could you please remove "simple" from the URI and include your PyPI local repository's name & verify if that works?

[Additional note]
Artifactory also supports the deployment of artifacts through the virtual repository. In order to enable it, we need to define the local repositories to be aggregated by the virtual repository as a target for deployment. It can be achieved by setting the Default Deployment Repository under the Virutal repository settings.

Comment: Using `https://my-repository.artifactory.company.local/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi` returns a 403, and trying `https://artifactory.company.local/artifactory/my-repository/api/pypi/pypi` gives me a 405. Via curl, I am able to push wheels so I know it's not _actually_ a permissions issues for my user/repository

Comment: You didn't try the correct url @geudrik, look more closely at Yuvarajan's answer.